# Another 3 level hierarchical regression

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have a dependent variable: rtln (log transformed reaction time) and 3 predictors: 
choicenum (ranging from 1 to 6), ifrelevant (0 and 1), and condition (0 and 1), and I have a variable with subject IDs.

I would like to estimate a model where choicenum is nested within subjects.
I use the following notation:

```
lmer(rtln~choicenum + ifrelevant + condition 
 + (1|subject/choicenum),    data=myData)
```

for some reason this estimates 5 fixed effects for choicenum.

- Here's the output: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/output.tiff
- Here's the dataset: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/data.csv
- Here's the stata output of what I'd like to get: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/output.pdf

Comment: you seem to be posting the same question using different variable names, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/error-message-when-estimating-group-level-interactions-lmer) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13161/testing-group-level-interactions-using-lmer).

Comment: so are you **really** sure you want to have `choicenum` nested within `subject`?

Comment: @wolf.rauch yes I want to have the exact same output as in stata. I want two grouping factors nested within each other.

Comment: Your stata output has ifIncongruent as a numeric variable. It does not correspond to your question here. You should make more of an effort to describe what you want.

Comment: @wolf.rauch I'm terribly sorry, I provided the wrong output. I've edited the question with the new (correct output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you have specified `choicenum` as a factor, but you assume that it is numeric.

If you specify `choicenum` as a factor in the fixed effects part, `lmer` will --- as you should know from the help pages of `lmer`, `lm` and the `R` Introduction, estimate effects comparing all factor levels to a 'baseline' level (see `?contr.treatment` and `?contrasts`), so that is why you get 5 entries for `choicenum` in the fixed effects part.

But you need a factor in the random effects part of the equation for `lmer`. So you might try the following:

First, specify `choicenum` as numeric in your data.frame. Then, run

```
m1 <- lmer(rtln~choicenum + ifrelevant + condition + (1|subject/as.factor(choicenum)), 
  data= YourData)
```

Of course you could also specify `... as.numeric(choicenum) ...`

Comment: I have specified choicenum<-as.numeric(choicenum) and then entered the code you pasted. R just freezes and processes for ever. Did you manage to run this code?

Comment: problem solved: first specify subject as factor choicenum as numeric and then your code works. thank you for resolving this problem, this finally solves every question for all of my posts

Comment: @wolf.rauch Do you know any literature that shows that a grouping variable (`choicenum`) can also be included as a fixed effect? As far as I know, it makes no sense but I may be wrong...

Comment: @Bernd-Weiss: As far as I understood DBR’s design, `choicenum` is a within-subjects ordered factor, so there should be no problem about its fixed effect. I had my problems with `choicenum` as a grouping factor, but now I think it might make a little sense. Beside its fixed effects, there might be different between-subjects variances at each level of `choicenum`.

Comment: @Bernd-Weiss: But I haven’t really worked it out, I mainly wanted to see if it works at all ;-) I guess the more sensible model is to include both fixed and random effects for `choicenum` and then maybe to check for heteroscedasticity at different levels of `choicenum`, i.e. using `weights=varIdent(form=~1|choicenum)` in `nlme`.

Comment: @wolf.rauch Thanks for your explanation! I am still not convinced but this is probably due to my lack of understanding. I am still thinking too much in terms of countries/counties or schools/classes etc. (which are the 'natural' grouping units in my field...).

Comment: @Bernd-Weiss: yes, I know about the schools/classes :-) I have that problem too. Try to think of every student (student in N) being taught by every teacher (in M) with N>>M, and there are *repeated measures* for students:teachers. Each teacher has a "fixed effect" (i.e. some are "better" than others), and there is also variability of the teacher effect *within students*. And yes, I think that it makes more sense to include a random coefficient for `choicenum` instead of a grouping factor.